# How to evaluate Gamma function by Newton-Cotes integration

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, gamma-function, numerical-calculus

I want to approximate $\Gamma(a)$ by using the trapezoidal rule and Simpson's rule. The concrete exercise I am doing suggests rewriting the integral to avoid $f(\infty)$. The rewriting goes like this:

$ \Gamma(a)= \int_{{0}}^{\infty}  x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}  \,dx\ = \int_{{0}}^{1}  x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}  \,dx\ + \int_{0}^{1}  x^{-1-\alpha}e^{-1/x}  \,dx\  $

Let's first use the trapezoidal rule. I know that the general form is:

$ \int_{{a}}^{b}  f(x)  \,dx\ \approx  \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}(b-a)\   $

So I was thinking of applying the trapezoidal rule to the first integral and then to the second integral, and then I could add up the two approximations as the final approximation. Let's apply this method to the first integral:

$ \int_{{0}}^{1}  x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}  \,dx\ \approx  \frac{f(0)+f(1)}{2}(1-0)\ = \frac{e^{-1}}{2}   $

No problem. But if I wan't to do the same thing to the next integral, then $f(a)=f(0)$ involves division by zero. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Both Trapezoidal and Simpson's (I thought they were versions of Newton-Cotes). Can I just use the limit of f(a) for a->0 from the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that $f(x)=x^{-1-a} e^{-1/x}$ is right-continuous (and even has right-derivatives of any order) at $x=0$, you can simply set $f(0)=0$. In practice this just means that you can disregard the first node in both the trapezoidal and Simpson's methods.